# How to parse multi-level JSON Array

Tags: c#, json, json.net, restsharp, json-deserialization

I am trying to parse multi-level json array, but I am getting the following exception:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Tractor.Models.UserDetails' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
```

Here is the json response:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": null,
  "userdetails": [
    {
      "ID": 9,
      "Name": "aleem",
      "Company_Name": null,
      "Email": null,
      "Password": null,
      "Created_Date": null,
      "Email_Confirm": null,
      "Token": null,
      "Phone": null,
      "Website": null,
      "allcompanies": [
        {
          "Name": "self",
          "allprojects": [
            {
              "ID": 1,
              "Name": "test"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "screens": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Below are the classes I have added to get the JSON Response:

```
class LoginApiResponse
{
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public int Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("userdetails")]
        public UserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }

    }

class UserDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Company_Name")]
    public string Company_Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Created_Date")]
    public string Created_Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Email_Confirm")]
    public string Email_Confirm { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Token")]
    public string Token { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Website")]
    public string Website { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("allcompanies")]
    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("screens")]
    public int Screens { get; set; }
}

class Company
    {
        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("allprojects")]
        public List<Project> Projects {get;set;}
    }

class Project
    {
        [JsonProperty("ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using the below code to serialize this JSON:

```
var response = client.Execute(request); 
var final = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginApiResponse>(response.Content);
```

Comment: `UserDetails` is an Array in Json

Answer (score 2):

The JSON requires `UserDetails` field to be an array (or list) of `UserDetails` objects:

```
class LoginApiResponse
{
    //.........
    [JsonProperty("userdetails")]
    public UserDetails[] UserDetails { get; set; }
    //                ^^
    // Alternatively, use List<UserDetails> instead of UserDetails[]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the `LoginApiResponse` class.

The Property `UserDetails` should be a `List<UserDetails>` instead of `UserDetails`. So you get:

```
class LoginApiResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userdetails")]
    public List<UserDetails> UserDetails { get; set; }

}
```

This is because you expect an Array/List in the JSON for `userdetails`:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": null,
  "userdetails": [
      { /* ... */ },
      { /* ... */ }
  ]
}
```

**Alternatively** (if you don't expect a list of userdetails) you can change the json (from a list to an object) too:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": null,
  "userdetails": 
      { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I do it is deserialize a JSON object into a dynamic variable, then access the properties you need on that dynamic variable, you can use those to initialise a model if you'd like.